# handlee and convert multiple data types in the same column to numeric

Tags: python, pandas, types, numeric

I am trying to clean my `Dataframe`. The problem is that I want to convert more than 300 different columns to numeric, but in the same column I have multiple data types.
As an example of `DataFrame`:

```
ID  MONOCITOS   EOSIN    EOSINOFILOS NORMOBLASTOS   
0   5   0.21    2   0   0.04    31.0
2   9   <0.22   False   0   0.04    33.0
5   12.8    0.16    0   0   0.02    sdfdr
6   No  0   fh  0   0.02    60.0
9   0   0.28    3   -   0.06    Nan
14  3   -   3   -   -   59.0
```

What is the best way to convert a column with different data types to numeric? Is there any module to perform this task automatically?
Thanks

Comment: I dont know a tool but you can go trough the columns and write a function which do this programmaticly. In Easy cases you can use: pd.to_numeric https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html

Comment: Use `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`

Comment: I have tried this solution, but it doesn´t work. As some values of the column are string data type the whole column type remains as an object type

Answer (score 0):

You can convert multiple columns like this:

```
df[["col1", "col2"]] = df[["col1", "col2"]].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

or change the entire dataframe:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

coerce will cause the non-convertible values to be `NaN`

Comment: This is not suitable for "300 different columns"

Comment: You could go over a set of columns at a time. For instance, use a loop that would convert 10 cols at a time

Comment: Yeah like:: for c in df.columns: column = df[c]

Comment: You can also just pass the whole `df` at once: `df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`

Comment: True. Passing the column names was just in the case trying to change it all at the same time could be too much. I will change to make it more explicit